# MATLAB: calls to system() do not exit, but rather hang at shell prompt

Tags: matlab

I have various matlab installations for Linux 64 bit, running Fedora 19/
For now, lets say I'm using MATLAB2010R.

I tried wiping my .matlab/ config and that didn't help.

```
>>>system('ls')
bash$   <hangs>
bash$ exit

foo
foobar

ans = 0
>>>
```

So I have to manually exit for the system call to return to the Matlab prompt.
This breaks various things, such as `copyfile`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dumb problem acutally...

From within matlab:

```
>>system('ls')
bash$ps Aux | grep user
```

we can see that I tcsh was called, then tcsh called a bash instance.

I set this up a long time ago, b/c I couldn't change my default shell very easily.
That is the whole problem...

Answer (score 0):

Though question is quite old, I am still answering in the hope to help someone having same issue.

I had the same issue. I managed to solve this issue by uncommenting one line in `.matlab7rc.sh` file in  directory.

open `.matlab7rc.sh` file and search for line

```
LDPATH_PREFIX='$MATLAB/sys/opengl/lib/$ARCH'
```

Above line is present three times in `.matlab7rc.sh` file for Matlab 2016. Uncomment all of them.

And it is also stated in above mentioned file as

> To always use the OpenGL libraries shipped with MATLAB uncomment the next line.

This works like charm. Now, Matlab is exiting normally.